# list all file from folder and subfolder in drive using c#

Tags: c#

I want to list all files in drive and i m also trying this code in c#. but i get unaurthorizedfileaccess exception.
plzz give me right solution so i can go ahead in my work....

```
try
{
    var files = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles("E:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    Method(files);           
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

```
static void Method(List<string> files)
{
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(files.Count);
}
```

Comment: Is UAC enabled on the machine?

Comment: Run as administrator?

Answer (score 2):

You can have method to get files in directory and recursively call that one as below

```
static void GetAllFiles(string path, IList<string> files)
{
    try
    {
        Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList()
            .ForEach(f => files.Add(f));

        Directory.GetDirectories(path).ToList()
            .ForEach(f => GetAllFiles(f, files));
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
       //Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

then you can print the results as below

```
 var files = new List<string>();
 GetAllFiles(path ,files); 
 Method(files);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's right your app could not have access rights to some folders (for ex: system folders), so you need to handle this  case. It's seems it's imposible to do this in one line. You need something like this:

```
    void DiscoverDirs(string where, List<string> files)
    {
        try
        {
            files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(where));
            foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(where))
            {
                DiscoverDirs(dir, files);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // no access fo this dir
        }
    }
```

And calling syntax:

```
   var list = new List<string>();
   DiscoverDirs("E:\\", list);
```

Notice that it could take a looooonnnng time.